# Deploy to a MySql database in Azure named with a dash

Tags: mysql, azure, tfs, deployment

I have a MySql database which I want to deploy to Azure. So, the database on Azure is already created, I am basically only modifying it:

```
use my-db;
drop existing_tables;
// create new tables etc.
```

But the problem is that my employer named the Azure database with a dash ( - ), and I don't have access to the Azure portal, in order to rename it. So now, when I try to deploy the database, I get the following error:

> couldn't create database

The detailed log shows that "there is a syntax error near my -db...".

I have tried modifying my script to

```
use "my-db";
use `my-db`;
```

even without the `use` statement at all, but none of it worked.

For deployment, I am using a TFS build pipeline stage called Azure Database for MySql Deployment.

Is there any chance of fixing this on my own?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the *Azure Database for MySQL Deployment* script.

Refer to the [Database name in MySQL command for Azure Database deployment is not escaped](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/8407) issue on GitHub.